# How can I manually install Windows Media Player on Windows 7 N?

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player

I inadvertently installed the 'N' version of Windows 7 Professional (via my MSDN license), the version where Microsoft is forced by the EU to offer Windows without Window Media Player.

A first pass through Microsoft's pages don't seem to offer a manual install path to WMP12 - any workarounds?

Comment: Use another media player?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Media Feature Pack for Windows 7 N and Windows 7 KN](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=31017ed3-166a-4c75-b90c-a6cef9b414c4)